# "Select is not defined" jQuery weather app tutorial

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have provided the following jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/joegerofsky/huo9r59p/

here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<meta name="viewport" width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0>
<style> body {padding: 0; margin: 0;} </style>


  </head>
<body>

<p>

City: <input id='city' value='Toronto'></input>
<br>
<button id='submit'>Submit</button>

</p>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../p5.min.js"></script>
<script src="../addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="../addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
<script src="weather.js"></script>
 </body>
```

here's my js:

```
var api_key = "&APPID=c0aa3c8995df1b0dd97032d0072333b3";

var api = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=";

var city = "Toronto";

var units = "&units=metric"

$( "#submit" ).click(function() {

 input = select('#city');

$(function(){

var url = api + input.value() + api_key + units;

$.getJSON(url, function(wd){
        console.log('got the data', wd);
})



})

});
```

My console says "select is not defined" on line 11.
I'm essentially trying to build the weather app from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4UoUqnjUC2c
Using jQuery instead of just p5js though. Can anyone help out?

Comment: Use `$('#city')` instead of `select('#city')`

Comment: And it should be `input.val()` not `input.value()`

Comment: thank you @MinhDuc !!! good ol' jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The `select()` function is property of p5.js. If you want to use jquery instead of p5, you should use the jquery selector that its `$('#id')` , in your case `$('#city')` .

Check the documentation of bought libraries :

- p5 : https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/select
- jquery : https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Greetings!!